# interpn returns diagonal instead of interpolated matrix

Tags: octave

Using `interpn` in octave I get an unexpected result:

```
Data=rand(10,3);
interpn(Data,[1,2,3],1:size(Data,2));
```

I would expect the first  three rows of Data but instead it returns a single row vector containing `[Data(1,1),Data(2,2,),Data(3,3)]`. Any explanation for this behaviour I missed in the documentation or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function File: VI = interpn (X1, X2, ..., V, Y1, Y2, ...)
Function File: VI = interpn (V, Y1, Y2, ...)

 Perform N-dimensional interpolation, where N is at least two.  Each
 element of the N-dimensional array V represents a value at a
 location given by the parameters X1, X2, ..., XN.  The parameters
 X1, X2, ..., XN are either N-dimensional arrays of the same size as
 the array V in the "ndgrid" format or vectors.  The parameters Y1,
 etc.  respect a similar format to X1, etc., and they represent the
 points at which the array VI is interpolated.

 If X1, ..., XN are omitted, they are assumed to be 'x1 = 1 : size
 (V, 1)', etc.  If M is specified, then the interpolation adds a
 point half way between each of the interpolation points.  This
 process is performed M times.  If only V is specified, then M is
 assumed to be '1'.
```

No. The first argument is your data (V) and since you are not specifying the X1 and X2, they are assumed to be 1:M and 1:N. You are then requesting to interpolate using your second and third arguments Y1 and Y2.

To accomplish what you want, you need to do:

```
[y1, y2] = meshgrid ([1 2 3], 1:columns (Data));
interpn (Data, y1, y2)
```

or to avoid intermediate variables (and easier real nd support):

```
interpn (Data, nthargout (1:2, @meshgrid, [1 2 3], 1:columns (Data)){:})
```

Comment: Thanks, for `[1,2,3,4]` I got the matrix which I expected which was very confusing. Your code transposes the result because you are using `meshgrid` which returns second dimension first. That`s because dimensions are ordered Y X Z in Matlab. Using `ngrid` fixes this.